# Getting CSS data from file using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json

I want jQuery to select a `background-color` from a `css` class which isn't in the document (although the `hover` uses the same color).

This is the code I've got at the moment:

```
<a id='changetext1'>
  <div class='tile color_red1'>text</div>
</a>
<a id='changetext2'>
  <div class='tile color_orange1'>text</div>
</a>
<div class='rightside color_red2' id='rightside'>some more text</div>
```

The rightside starts off as `color_red2`, but I'd like it to change to `color_orange2` on clicking the `color_orange1` `div`. And of course change it to `color_red2` when the red `div` is being clicked.

The text and colors come from a sql database and are put into jquery with `JSON`

```
function rightSideData(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, d) {
        $("#changetext" + d.id).on('click', function() {
        //Change the background color to match the :hover color of the right div TODO
        });
    }
});
```

The part with switching the text works fine, I'm stuck at the changing the `background-color` property. The color can be retrieved from the `JSON` data (`d.color`), but I cannot figure out how to get the `.color_orange2` `background-color` from the `css` file.

EDIT: The solution is the following:

```
var color = window.getComputedStyle($(".color_"+d.color+"1").get(0),':hover').getPropertyValue('background-color');
$('.color_red2').css("background-color",color);
```

Comment: Two options: Either utilize a switch condition for retrieving the value from the JSON object, or, use jQuery to create a `<style></style>`, then append it to the head.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot access your CSS directly. jQuery's interaction is limited to acting on the DOM elements (setting, retrieving, removing class attributes, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.getComputedStyle) to evaluate divs' classes. I think something like

```
var color = window.getComputedStyle($('.color_red1').get(0),':hover').getPropertyValue('background-color');
```

might possibly work...

Comment: This works quite nicely. I updated the question with the answer in code.

Comment: Good to hear that. It was just a blind shot :)..haven't tried it.

Answer (score 2):

Can you just not use JQuery's addClass('color_orange2') and removeClass('color_red2') to get the result you want?

Also, you can have :hover and :active in your CSS so you dont even have to use JQuery if the change is only meant to be seen while the user is clicking. But if you want permanent I suggest just changing the classes up.

Comment: Fixed it with this, however my code is sloppy (as I have 5 different colors, which means 5 times removeClass(). Any suggestions?